# Unable to get frequency on oscilloscope

Tags: microcontroller, embedded, microprocessor, soc, nor-flash

I am using NOR flash IS25WP256D in my project. I configured a frequency of 80 MHz and a bus width of 4 in DTS, but when I observed with an oscilloscope I got 62 MHz.

Why does this happen?

These are the DTS changes I made:

[image]
[image]

Comment: And what is the microcontroller and what is the clock source for the SPI module and does Linux know all of this?

Comment: The entry is called "spi-**max**-frequency" (emphasis by me). It might be allowed to clock slower.

Comment: Please show a waveform from the oscilloscope

Comment: Sounds like you have a clock frequency of 250MHz somewhere.  Divide by 3 is somewhat over 80MHz and /4 is 62.5

Comment: What is your sweep rate of your scope in the picture?